# How to filter post by category in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am currently trying to make a relation between 3 tables.

```
post
    id
    name
category
    id
    name
post_category
    id
    post_id
    category_id
```

Database

```
post
|   1   |   post1   |
|   2   |   post2   |
|   3   |   post3   |
category
|   1   |    cat1   |
|   2   |    cat2   |
|   3   |    cat3   |
post_category
|   1   |   1   |   1   |
|   2   |   2   |   1   |
|   3   |   3   |   2   |
|   3   |   2   |   2   |
|   3   |   1   |   3   |
```

Model Post.php

```
public function getCategory()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post_category');
}
```

PostController.php

```
$data = Post::with('getCategory')->get();
```

It returns correct post list.
Now i want to filter the post by category. I try, but it not working

```
$categoryId = [1,2];
$data = Post::with('getCategory')->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
$query->whereIn('id', $categoryId);
})->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

please help me
use Laravel 5.4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you use `whereHas` or any other method in the relationship area, the first parameter refers to the method of your model (`getCategory`), not the table. Look at @Flame answer. That's the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently everything is fine!

One suggestion is to add two more parameters to the `belongsToMany` method, like:

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post_category', 'post_id', 'category_id');
}
```

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_belongsToMany

Comment: I try, but it not work.
`(1/1) ErrorException
compact(): Undefined variable: operator` I use laravel 5.4

Comment: it's probably version 5.4 [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936)

Maybe the solution is to use something like:

`DB::select ('select * from post p where id in (select (post_id) from post_category ua where category_id = ?)');`

or

`$post_category = DB::table('post_category')->where('category_id', ?)->get();`
`$post = DB::table('post')->whereIn('id', $post_category->pluck('post_id'))->get();`

Comment: Yeah! I used your way. it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your `getCategory()` function to simply `category()`. That makes the relation names much more straightforward and probably fixes your issue.

THEN, you should be able to call `whereHas('category', ...)`.

If it still does not work, simply chain a `->toSql()` to any of your queries and debug the actual query that way.

Comment: I use and error `(1/1) ErrorException.
compact(): Undefined variable: operator`

Comment: @sawyer i have no clue where that is coming from. The error should point you exactly where to look.

Comment: it worked the way of  Jessé kalil Martins Da Silva, thank you
`$post_category = DB::table('post_category')->where('category_id', ?)->get(); $post = DB::table('post')->whereIn('id', $post_category->pluck('post_id'))->get();`